# Android Service: Queue events/tasks initiated in the UI until the Service is started?

Tags: android, service, queue

I have a ListView which displays information about some entities (all of the same type). Every entity has a state and depending on that the ListItem can have a different look. Furthermore a click on a ListItem does a specific operation depending on the state of the entity.

When in state A the entity should be passed to a service which uses it to do some operation.

The service should be started only when needed. So if the user clicks on the ListItem the service will be started and the entity should be passed to it. Then the service does some operation and the state of the entity changes. This will result in a change of the look of the ListItem the entity belongs to.

- Simple case: The service is already started and bound so when the
  user clicks on the ListItem the servicemethod to pass the entity can
  be called directly.
- Difficult case: The service is not started and the user clicks on the
  ListItem.

What is the best way to deal with the second case? Saving the entities in a queue, wait for the service to be started and pass the queue or is there a more elegant way?
The user could have clicked on several ListItems before the service has started.

Or is it better to keep the service running in background all the time to avoid this? Then the question is if the binding of the service is fast enough so that if a user clicks on a ListItem the reference to the service is already bound.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How beefy is the `Service`? If it isn't doing things all the time in a background thread then I'd say the most responsive, effective way is to maintain the binding to the `Service` while the `Activity` containing your `ListView` is operational. That way, you don't have a "difficult case". Remember: while the user is using your application actively in the foreground, that's obviously what they want the device's resources used for.

Be a good citizen, though, and unbind the service on `onPause()` and rebind in `onResume()` so that the `Service` *can* be killed if needed. I mean sure, it can be killed anyway at any time, but it's part of being a responsible Android citizen.

Don't forget that `Service` entities *by default* do all their processing in the main thread. If your `Service` does perform heavy lifting on the `onClick()` processing you're talking about, you my wish to have it operate in a separate thread or even put a different process in the manifest.